# Mirror database stuck in Restoring... state?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, mirroring

I just setup mirroring between a principal and mirror server.  I am following some steps a coworker left for me as I have not done this before.

At one point, I had to backup the principal database which I did with

```
USE MASTER
GO
BACKUP DATABASE MyDB
    TO DISK ='D:\Backups\MyDBFullBackup.bak'
GO
BACKUP LOG MyDB
    TO DISK='D:\Backups\MyDB_LogBackup.trn'
GO
```

Then I copied these files to the mirror server and restored them with

```
USE MASTER
GO
RESTORE DATABASE MyDB
    FROM DISK='D:\Backups\MyDBFullBackup.bak'
    WITH NORECOVERY
GO
RESTORE LOG MyDB
    FROM DISK='D:\Backups\MyDB_LogBackup.trn'
    WITH NORECOVERY
GO
```

After that I finalized the mirror (already did all the cert creation/copying over) with

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB
    SET PARTNER='TCP://192.168.1.5:5022
GO
```

on the principal and mirror databases (with the appropriate IP changes).

This all seems to have worked in so far as when I run the query

```
SELECT [mirroring_State_desc], [mirroring_role_desc], [mirroring_partner_name], [mirroring_partner_instance]
FROM sys.database_mirroring
WHERE [database_id]=db_id('MyDB')
```

These all look right when run on principal or witness, the role is correct, it's synchronized, and the partner name/ip are all correct.

The thing that I am worried about but am not sure I should be is when I open up SSMS on the mirror server, the database looks like

[image]

Is this a problem?  Or is this database since its a mirror that's constantly being updated (not now in development but in general) it's always Restoring...?   Not sure if this is a problem and if so how to figure out what is wrong.

I am able to do `ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET PARTNER FAILOVER` and I see the effects in both databases, the principal changes to mirrored and vice versa, but whatever is the mirror still has the `Restoring...` that doesn't seem to go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be correct, I think there are two possible mirroring states you will always see if mirroring is healthy and working as expected:  Mirror,Synchronized/Restoring or Mirror,Synchronizing/Restoring.

Comment: Thank you.  Never done this before so I was just making sure everything is correct.